# Android, Is it possible to wrap APK files (created by others) in order to show advertisement?

Tags: android, apk

Assume that I have an appstore. developers submit their application in this store.

My question is, is it possible to wrap those application with my application. What i mean?
I want to show some advertisements after application lunches by user and then let user to go to its application. is it possible?

I think it should be impossible because it is a kind of hacking others code. Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's possible to wrap in a way you have described, since launching of external application from Android viewpoint is just launching of another `Intent`, so right before launching external application you will have a chance to start advertisement

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.another.application"); 
 //show advertisement
 //...
 //start application
 startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: is there any way to prevent it ?

Comment: where do we keep the application/apk?